# Android: how to get grid-view item Tag by its position from with-in Another grid-view's set-on-item-click listener function?

Tags: java, android

How can I get a `grid-view`'s item tag by its position and have to get from another `grid-view`'s item click listener function.

```
gridview2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
{
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                            int position, long id) 
    {
        int i=(Integer)gridview1.getChildAt(gridview1s_position).getTag();---> it is returning Null     
    }  
});
```

MY `gridview1.setOnitemClicklistener` and `gridview2.setonitemclicklistener` are in the same file (`MainActivity.java`)

But the `gridview1` adapter is a `ImageAdapter.java`(this is for setting the images in the gridview1) and `gridview2` adapter is `imageadapter2.java`(this is for setting black images so that the `gridview2` looks like a box with rows and columns, otherwise it is showing like a Bold line because we didn't put anything in the gridview)

```
gridview1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,int position, long id) 
        {  
            int tag=(Integer)gridview1.getChildAt(position).getTag();//this returning the tag
        }
     });
```

ImageAdapter1.java

```
 public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    if(arg1!=null)
    {
        imv=(ImageView)arg1;
    }
    else
    {
        imv=new ImageView(cont);
        imv.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(40,40));
        imv.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imv.setPadding(0,0,0,0);

    }
    imv.setImageResource(imageid[arg0]);//imageid aray is having drawable images
    imv.setTag(imageid[arg0]);
    return imv;

}
```

gridview2

```
gridview2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    { 
      ImageAdapter ia=new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext());
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,int position, long id) 
         {  
                ImageView imv;
                  if(v!=null)
            {
                imv=(ImageView)v;
            }
            else
            {
                imv=new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
                imv.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(40,40));
                imv.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imv.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
                imv.setBackgroundColor(5555);

            }

                  imv.setImageResource(ia.imageid[tt]); 
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally myself i got the solution for my question.Thank you for all who gave their valuable suggestions.

i saved the tag of a particullar cell of grid-view1 in a variable and used that variable in the grid-view2.

Answer (score 0):

using `getChildAt` might be too cumbersome for something like this because it only useful for making references to views that are in view and re-orders its indexes to match this. I don't know enough about where your other `GridView` is positioned to pursue this avenue further.

But regardless, the way i'd do something like this is to make an intermediary collection between the two adapters. as in one adapter holds all the tags in an indexed collection and then you could make some sort of reader `get` method. at the very least, this way of doing it would put my mind at ease.

```
gridview2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

        int i = gridview1.getTagFromPosition(position);

    }  
});
```

then in the `gridView1` adapter something like:

```
private int[] tagCollection;

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // .....
    convertView.setTag(tagCollection[position]);
    return convertView;
}

public int getTagFromPosition(int position) {
    return tagCollection[position];
}
```

i at least hope the idea comes across so that you can modify it for however is practical for how your objects are getting modified and accessed.