# The tags for the GridView items are applying only when they are visible?

Tags: java, android, gridview

I have a GridView which is scrollable: only some of the items will be displayed and only after scrolling down the GridView. We can see the other items. The problem is, I am setting the tags for all the items in the GridView, but by tracing the LogCat I came to know that it is not accepting to set the tags for the non-visible items in the GridView(I mean the items which are inside the grid, but at that time are not on the screen)

Before scrolling:

[image: Starting Screen]

After scrolling:

[image: After scrolling]

Only after scrolling down the other items the tags are applied.

How can I set the tags for all the items of the grid, even if they are on the screen or off the screen?

Comment: Provide some code : how do you set the tag ? Logcat output ? what are you logging ?

Comment: @ben75 how to accept when i didn't find any helpful answers?

Comment: here's my code [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14002964/android-how-to-get-grid-view-item-tag-by-its-position-from-with-in-another-grid]

Comment: 9 questions... none of them is helpful ? Why are you still asking new questions here if you don't receive helpful answers ?

Comment: if you didn't get the job for the first time or second time or third time will you stop trying? may be you do. But i wont and will never. peace friend :)

Comment: yes friend your right :) but i have tried all the answers,but my fate none of those helped me regarding the grid-view problems :( thank you for your suggestion mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you set the Tag in the `getView` method and this method is only called by the framework when the view need to be displayed.

Don't know exactly what you need to do with the view tag, but I think that instead of trying to get the data from a non-displayed view, you must get it from your ImageAdapter (`ia.imageid[]`).

**EDIT:**

To answer more preciselly to your question:

> How can I set the tags for all the items of the grid, even if they are on the screen or off the screen?

As soon as the view doesn't always exists when it is not displayed: you cannot do it.

I suggest you to explain why you need those tags... may be you can use an alternative solution than view tag to accomplish your final needs.

Anyway, if you really need to have tag on view that aren't displayed yet:

1. Initialize a view array in `onCreate` method.
2. Populate this array with all your views (and set the tag)
3. modify `getView` method of your adapter to return the view from your array of view instead of creating the view.

Please note that I don't recommend this solution since it will consume more resources.

Comment: i removed the setting tag in the get-view and tried to set the tags in gridview1 set-on-item-click-listener.But this is also not working.only some cells are getting tagged

Answer (score 0):

Finally myself i got the solution for my question.Thank you for all who gave their valuable suggestions.
Thank you @ben75

> i checked the position of present clicked item and then applied the tag so if the user want to select the item which is presently not on the focus he has to scroll the grid and then have to select the item and then only the tag will be applied.

Comment: you're welcome ;-) If my answer help you to solve your problem... please vote up.